# How to change the date format (DD/MON/YY) in OpenOffice spreadsheets?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I want to change the date format from default format to another format (with months)in OpenOffice spreedsheets.

Answer (score 4):

How do you want it to appear?

- Select the cells you want to format
- Select Format, Cells
- Select the Numbers tab
- Select the word Date under Category
- Select the format you like

For a format that is not listed, click in the Format Code text box and enter the format you would like: D for day, DD for leading zero in day, M for month, MM for leading zero in month, MMM for 3 letter abbreviation for month, MMMM for full month, YY for 2 digit year, YYYY for 4 digit year, NN for 3 letter abbreviation of day of week, NNNN for full day of week. You can also add any other character you want: /-.